# Can't edit TS files in VS for Mac

Tags: macos, typescript, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to make a SPA with .Net Core and Angular.

So I followed this tutorial: [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

It runs perfectly. Even if I open the solution in VS4Mac.

The problem is that I can't edit the typescript files. I've searched everywhere!

I have the latest version of everything involved. NodeJS, VS4Mac, etc...

**Update after the comments bellow:**

- I've reinstalled VS for Mac and it didn't help.
- I can see and open them in VS. But as soon as I start writing, a box
  appears with a message "no completions found".
- I can open and edit in other editors.
- I even did "chmod 777" to a file just to see if it were the
  permissions, but it didn't help.
- I'd tried to disable IntelliSense, but No difference.

I have no idea of what is the reason why VS for Mac can't edit ts. And I'd like to use a native IDE, instead of a VM. **Could it be that VS for Mac CAN'T edit typscript altogether?** I haven't been able to prove otherwise. **Has anybody else been able to edit TS with this IDE?**

Comment: Please help us understand why you can't edit the typescript files. Do you see them in VS? If you do, what happens when you click on them? Have you tried opening them in other code editors?

Comment: Yes, I can see and open them in VS. But as soon as I start writing, a box appears with a message "no completions found". I can open and edit in other editors. I even did "chmod 777" to a file just to see if it were the permissions, but it didn't help.

Comment: So the TypeScript autocomplete doesn't seem to be working. I'd try to disable IntelliSense first, and report back.

Comment: No difference. Well, now the message doesn't appear... ;)

Comment: So if the message doesn't appear now, what is preventing you from editing the TypeScript file? I'm not advocating disabling IntelliSense as a sustainable solution, just to arrive at the root cause.

Comment: That is my original question. I have no idea of what is the reason why vs for mac can't edit ts. And I'd like to use a native IDE, instead of a VM.

Could it be that VS for Mac CAN'T edit ts altogether? I haven't been able to prove otherwise. Has anybody else been able to edit TS with this IDE?

Comment: I've never used VS on Mac. On Windows, I've never had any problem working with TypeScript files on VS.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I've used VS in a Win VM. And everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to create and edit TypeScript (TS) files in Visual Studio for Mac (Version 7.1, screenshot below). Now, as far as I can tell, the IDE does not support TS compilation out of the box, so you'll have to compile yourself via tsc (TypeScript Compiler) or another transpiler (ex. Babel) with [TS plugin](https://github.com/babel/babylon).

[image]

That being said, a better editing experience for TypeScript on Mac is [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/#section=mac), an IDE from JetBrains, which supports TypeScript out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got it running now. The git management is somewhat limited, but every thing is going great now!